Type Conversion in VSTO VB.NET from Range to Range?
I have a VSTO Excel project with the following code:
Dim start_row As Integer = 5, start_col As Integer = 1
Dim start_cell As Range = Cells(start_row, start_col)

Hovering the Cells function gives it as a function that returns a Range. However, when building with Option Strict On I get the following build error:
BC30512 Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'Range'.

I can fix this with a DirectCast but I'm confused why the cast is necessary, Cells is supposed to return a Range not an Object.

You may also want to consider not using Option Strict On.  It ultimately doesn't play very nicely with Excel interop as you end up needing extensive DirectCast usage.

Just starting with VSTO but I’ll try that as well. I’ll put some functionality in a separate module where I can turn it on without too much hassle.

That makes sense.  I could have added to my previous comment that, if I remember correctly, one of the major drivers for dynamic in C# to get late-binding-like behavior was to get better behavior working with the Office object models.

The Cells property returns Range, but that is not what you are storing in start_cell. If you notice, the Cells property does not accept arguments, and you are supplying two.
What you are storing in start_cell is the result of indexing the Range object returned by Cells with its indexer, and that returns Object. Essentially, it is
Dim start_cell As Range = Cells.[_Default](start_row, start_col)

This matches the behaviour of the underlying COM object model.

Thanks for also making the context clear! Using DirectCast is the best way to solve this?

Yes, it is.....
